# BFS and DFS on Adjacency List

Tags: c++, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search, adjacency-list

So I know the basics of Breadth First Search and Depth First Search on graphs but I can't seem to figure out how to perform both of them on a adjacency list. Each search starts at 0.

0 -> 5 -> 2 -> 1 -> 6

1 -> 7 -> 0

2 -> 7 -> 0

3 -> 5 -> 4

4 -> 6 -> 5 -> 7 -> 3

5 -> 0 -> 4 -> 3

6 -> 4 -> 0

7 -> 1 -> 2 -> 0 -> 4

I'm not sure where to start. I need to learn this so if you could please explain that would be great.

Comment: You'll want some way to avoid going back to nodes you've already visited, since that will lead to an infinite loop. Have you thought about how to store adjacencies yet?

Comment: Try to perform BFS and DFS on the representation of graphs you are more familiar with(matrix, objects), then performing them on adjacent list should be easier.

Answer (score 10):

The adjacency list tells you which nodes you can get to in 1 hop from each node. In your example, node 0 can get to node 5, node 2, node 1, and node 6.

I will just explain the case for BFS as once you get it you will likely have no problem with the case for DFS.

In BFS, the pseudocode goes like this:

```
Let graph be your adjacency list.
bool visited[num_nodes]; // Array of booleans to keep track if a node was visited.
for (int i = 0; i < num_nodes; i++)  // Set status of all nodes to be not visited.
  visited[i] = false;
start_node = 0; // E.g. start BFS at node 0.
visited[start_node] = true;
queue = Queue(); // Queue for keeping track of which node to check next
queue.append(start_node);
while (!queue.empty()) // While there is still nodes to check
{
 node = queue.pop_front(); // Get the node at the front of the queue.
 // For each of the neighbor of this node
 // This is where we make use of the adjacency list which tells us which nodes are the neighbors
 // of some other nodes.
 neighbors_of_node = graph[node];
 for (int i = 0; i < neighbors_of_node.size(); i++)
 {
  neighbor = neighbors_of_node[i];
  if (!visited[neighbor]) // If this node was not visited previously
  {
   do_something_with(neighbor);
   visited[neighbor] = true; // Indicate that we have visited this neighbor node.
   queue.append(neighbor);
  }
 }
}
```

The code above will visit all nodes reachable from your start node. Now what happens if your graph is not a fully connected component? If the requirement is to visit all nodes, then you will need to repeatedly perform BFS starting from one of the remaining nodes at the end of a BFS. How you choose the order depends on your problem. That will be something for you to think about.